# Error in TeX Live after Windows crash

Tags: errors, texlive, windows

My Windows 10 machine crashed while I was updating TeX Live.

Now, when I launch TeX Live Manager I got this error:

[image]

Is there a way to recover it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody seems to know the answer, I solved reinstalling TeX Live 2021.

I went to `C:\texlive\2021\tlpkg\installer` and run `uninst.bat`.

I removed the directory `C:\texlive\2021` (already almost empty after running `uninst.bat`).

I reinstalled TeX Live 2021, as usual, running `install-tl-windows.exe` of [the TeX Live site](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

All up and running now.