# Is the TeX Live 2023 Windows binary compatible with Windows 7?

Tags: texlive, texlive-2023

I'm running **Windows 7 Professional (64-bit)**, which Microsoft no longer supports.  (I realize that I'm continuing to use Windows 7 at my own risk. But I'm physically disabled and use some assistive technology software that doesn't work on Windows 10/11.  I'm looking into alternative software, so that I can upgrade my operating system to Windows 10/11 or macOS, but I need some more time.)

Currently, I have **TeX Live 2020** installed.  I'd like to update my distribution, so I was thinking to *uninstall* **TeX Live 2020** and *install* **TeX Live 2023**.  But I'd like to have some indication whether **2023** will work -- can be expected to work -- before I uninstall **2020** (which is working; it's just an old distribution).  ***Does anyone here know?***

Here's the [page for TeX Live on Windows](https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html).

- The link to the installer `install-tl-windows.exe` is given in the "Easy install" section on that page.
- In the "64- and 32-bit binaries" section on that page, it states, "For users of Windows XP, the 2017 edition is the last one which they still can use." But I don't see any mention of Windows 7 compatibility.

***Does anyone here know?*** Or is there a particular TeX Live user group or mailing list I should query?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but you can have multiple TeX Live distributions living happily on a single machine so there should be no need to uninstall your 2020 version before installing the 2023 version. But the best place to ask this question would be the [TeX Live mailing list](https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but as for my experience a TeX Live distribution is very easy to uninstall: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618155/101651. You can try to install TeX Live 2023 and if it gives you errors, unistall it afterwards.

Comment: Also, TL 2023 and onward will only supply 64bit binaries, so you first need to figure out whether you have a 64bit or 32bit version of Windows 7. If you have 32bit then you can't run the current version for sure. See [How do I determine whether Windows 7 is 32-bit or 64-bit?](//superuser.com/q/1252158)

Comment: Sorry you say at the beginning that you're running the 64bit version, so I would guess that you can run TL2023.

Comment: And it's explicitly stated [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-40001.2) that Windows 7 is supported.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from the [TeX Live Guide 2023](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-40001.2):

> As to Windows: Windows 7 and later are supported. Windows Vista may
> still mostly work, but TeX Live will no longer even install on Windows
> XP or earlier. TeX Live includes 64-bit executables for Windows.

This combined with the proviso that only 64bit binaries are supported, so long as your version of Windows 7 is 64bit, then it is in fact supported.

Furthermore, there's no need to uninstall older versions; multiple years of TeX Live can live happily on a single machine without interfering with each other.